# How to use purge css without webpack?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I use Ruby on Rails 5.1 for my project. I would like to remove unused css from my project by using [PurgeCss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss) like mentioned [here](https://discuss.rubyonrails.org/t/use-purgecss-to-remove-unused-css/80173).
But because Rails 5.1 does not use webpack on default, I don't know how to run `Purgecss`.

How can I use this package in my application?

Thanks in advance.